# Find a word with an apostrophe in PDF using pymupdf

Tags: python, pdf, highlight, pymupdf

I am using PyMuPDF from the fitz package to search and highlight words in a PDF. How to I find a word with an apostrophe in it? In my example code, text_instances will be empty. If you search for 'her' or "'", then text_instances will not be empty. Not sure what the problem is with the two strings concatenated.

Here is my example code:

```
import fitz

# READ IN PDF

doc = fitz.open("FILE.pdf")

page = doc[0]

text = "her's"

text_instances = page.searchFor(text)
```

Comment: Have you tested only for ' or also for ` and similar apostrophe-like characters?

Comment: @mkl great suggestion. ` is not found either on its own or in a string like her`s.

Comment: There are other apostrophe-like unicode characters, merely not on my cellular phone keyboard.